# Memory leak when resizing animated gif with ImageMagick

Tags: memory-leaks, resize, imagemagick, animated-gif, magickwand

I'm trying to resize animated gifs with ImageMagick MagickWand, but get some small memory leaks. ~3 Mb per 400 gifs. I`m not 100% sure if I'm using MagickWand right.

```cpp
MagickWandGenesis();
MagickCore::MagickWand *magick_wand = NewMagickWand();
MagickCore::MagickWand *magick_wand2 = NewMagickWand();

for(std::vector<string>::iterator it = gifs.begin(); it != gifs.end(); ++it)
{   
    inputFileName = "C:\\Projects\\gifs\\" + *it + ".gif";
    outputFileName = "C:\\Projects\\gifs\\out\\" + *it + ".gif";

    MagickReadImage(magick_wand, inputFileName.c_str());

    int width = MagickGetImageWidth (magick_wand);
    int height = MagickGetImageHeight (magick_wand);

    magick_wand2 = MagickCoalesceImages(magick_wand);
    ClearMagickWand(magick_wand);

    if(width > THUMBNAIL_WIDTH)
    {
        height = static_cast<int>(height * THUMBNAIL_WIDTH / width);
        width = 144;
    }

    if(height > THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT)
    {
        width = static_cast<int>(width * THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT / height);
        height = 144;
    }

    MagickResetIterator(magick_wand2);
    while (MagickNextImage(magick_wand2) != MagickFalse)
        MagickResizeImage(magick_wand2, width, height, MitchellFilter, 1 );

    magick_wand = MagickOptimizeImageLayers(magick_wand2);
    ClearMagickWand(magick_wand2);

    MagickWriteImages(magick_wand, outputFileName.c_str(), MagickTrue);             
    ClearMagickWand(magick_wand);
}

DestroyMagickWand(magick_wand);
DestroyMagickWand(magick_wand2);
MagickWandTerminus();
```

I've tried to use one MagickWand instead of two, but then functions don't work properly and leaks are even higher. I've also tried to initialize MagickWand inside the for-loop, but it didn't help. With this code gifs are resized and optimized properly. Memory leaks where detected by `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`. They are also noticeable with Windows Task Manager.

Comment: what's the version of ImageMagick?

Comment: I`ve been using ImageMagick 6.7.8-4 Q8 x64 RL